# Javascript - How to detect element's offsetTop changes?

Tags: javascript, html

**How to detect element's offsetTop changes?**
And other element's properties..

Here's a snippet where I try to place a `MutationObserver` on the tested `div`, but the observer is never triggered when I make the header `div` above bigger (by writting some text in it).

```js
// get the test element
var testElement = document.getElementById('test');
// build the observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log("Observer triggered! YES!!");
})
// place it, listen to attributes and datas changes
.observe(testElement, {
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
});


// --- test ---
console.log("The test div is at " + testElement.offsetTop + "px from the top.");
console.log("Writting in the header div (to make it bigger)..");

document.getElementById("header").innerText = "Header text changed";

console.log("The test div is at " + testElement.offsetTop + "px from the top after header text changed.");
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not easy way to do it except using pole which is nasty, or just tapping on the element to check it's positions.

There is this blog: [Jquery Plug-in](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/12/jQuery-CSS-Property-Monitoring-Plugin-updated)

It provides a good solution for IE and Firefox but does not fair with Web Kit.